# jquery animation loop not working proprly

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

i have this loop that animates six divs the problem is the animation is not working and the i got the feeling that there is something wrong with my loop

the jquery code:

```
while (true)
    {

        $(".tabs").children().each(function(index, value) {
           // alert($(value).css("top"));
            if (($(value).css("top") === '0px' && $(value).css("left") === '0px') || ($(value).css("top") === '0px' && $(value).css("left") === '316px'))
            {
                $(value).animate({
                    left: '+=316px'
                }, 1000);
            }
            else if (($(value).css("top") === '296px' && $(value).css("left") === '0px') || ($(value).css("top") === '592px' && $(value).css("left") === '0px'))
            {
                $(value).animate({
                    top: '-=296px'
                }, 1000);
            }
            else if (($(value).css("top") === '592px' && $(value).css("left") === '316px') || ($(value).css("top") === '592px' && $(value).css("left") === '632px'))
            {
                $(value).animate({
                    left: '-=316px'
                }, 1000);
            }
            else if ($(value).css("top") === '0px' && $(value).css("left") === '632px')
            {
                $(value).animate({
                    top: '+=592px'
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
        if ($(".tabs .tab").eq(j).css("top") === '0px' && $(".tabs .tab").eq(j).css("left") === '316px') {
            break;
        }
    }
```

}

the html

```
<div class="container">
<div class="tabs">
    <div class="tab" id="news">
        <h2>NEWS &<br>EVENTS</h2>
        <div class="tab-content"></div>
        <div class="tab-arrow"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab" id="services">
        <h2>PRODUCTS<br>& SERVICES</h2>
        <div class="tab-content"></div>
        <div class="tab-arrow"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab" id="partners">
        <h2>PARTNERS</h2>
        <div class="tab-content">

            </div>
        <div class="tab-arrow"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab" id="clients">
        <h2>CLIENTS</h2>
        <div class="tab-content"></div>
        <div class="tab-arrow"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab" id="search">
        <h2>SEARCH<br>OUR WEB</h2>
        <div class="tab-content"></div>
        <div class="tab-arrow"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab" id="findus">
        <h2>FIND US<br>ONLINE</h2>
        <div class="tab-content"></div>
        <div class="tab-arrow"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i hope some one can help me to solve the problem

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle for the same?

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: What do you mean exactly with _"the animation is not working"_? What is happening and what should be happening instead?

Comment: no errors in the console

Comment: the browser freeze as if the loop not breaking at all then the browser show message to stop the script after script stops a random animation happend

Comment: Your loop never stops then. You are having infinite loop issues.

Comment: but there is an if condition to break the loop ??  Gezzasa

Comment: You must not make a function within a loop

Comment: @MoneerKamal double check you condition. it sounds like it is always true. Also as user3811714 said, place the function outside of the loop and just call it in the loop.

Comment: You should utilize window.setInterval(); for this type of operation to prevent page lock ups.